# Mount shared SAN storage on one machine as read/write but read-only on others

Tags: linux, mount, load-balancer, san

I am writng a golang web application that will allow users to upload files and later retrieve them.
Application is divided in two parts

Part-1: Web-portal, it will be hosted on multiple linux web-severs with load-balancing.

Part-2: Upload-Service, it will be hosted on single linux server.

Instead of uploading files to all servers, i would like to save all files to shared SAN storage.

My question is, is it possible to mount same SAN storage on Upload-server with read and write both, but on all other servers as Read-only (as below) ?

[image]

So there will be single point to upload (write) and multiple points to serve files (read) to clients.

Will this config work and be safe for load-balanced environment?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Unix permissions were invited at '70s.

Comment: @IporSircer thanks for your comment. But will such config be safe for load-balanced encironment?

Comment: I think loadbalancing works on a totally different protocol. And you can use cachefilesd any time.